# Devices and Printers in Windows 7 not loading

Tags: windows-7, printer, control-panel

When I open the "Devices and Printers" window, the green status bar gets all the way to the end and then just stops with no items showing in the window. I left the window open for 45min with no change.

I have tried several fixes I've found from searching, turning on the bluetooth service, stopping/starting the printer spooler service, increasing the size of the registry and nothing works.

I had a colleague log onto my machine with his AD credentials and he had the same issue, so it doesn't appear to be an issue with my profile. Any ideas? Below are my desktop specs:

```
Windows 7 Pro 64-bit SP1
Dell Optiplex 790
Intel Core i5-2400 @ 3.1GHz
8gigs of RAM
500gig SATA HDD
```

Comment: Run an `SFC /Scannow` to ensure there are no missing/damaged system files.

Comment: Ran sfc /scannow, it found errors and repaired them, but the problem remains. I killed and restarted explorer.exe after it was finished as well.

Comment: Instead of just killing explorer.exe, reboot the machine.

Comment: Restarted, still not working.

Comment: The fact that it repaired anything tells me you have OS corruption. Test your disks and file systems, ensure they are good, then try a system restore. And/or get your IT staff to reimage the OS onto that machine.